# Oauth - authorization code flow with pkce - security implications of using localhost as redirect_uri

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Is there any security implications of using localhost as the redirect uri?

Mostly, localhost will be served via HTTP as ssl certificate is not installed in the dev environment. In Azure ad, if it is not localhost, then it should start with https.

But, can an attacker use localhost to get the token after he/she gets the client id from the url during authorization? I am curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `localhost` in redirect_uris is allowed mostly to accommodate developers. But even if you allow it in production and an attacker gets to add or change the `redirect_uri` query parameter in the authorization request, it would still be harmless.

After the authorization server authenticates the victim and gets their consent, it responds to the victim's user agent (browser) with a `HTTP 302` status code and a `Location` header with the authorization code as one of the query parameters. When the victim's browser follows that redirect, the `localhost` host address refers to the victim's machine. There's no way for the attacker to intercept that unless the attacker has code running on the victim's machine already (at which point the battle is already lost).